Can I read a PIC24FJ128GA010 hex file from the microntroller using a pickit3?
I'm working on a proejct where I have a functional device and some old code with no instructions and no .x project file (abandoned project).
I want to recompile the old code and reprogram the PIC24FJ128GA010 before altering the source code.  Unfortunately, this risks bricking the old device especially as the previously used toolchain is unknown.
I have been advised to read the hex file from the microcontroller first and use this as a backup if the code I compile fails to program correctly, I can reprogram the device with the code that was on it.
I am using a pickit3 and mplabx to work with the PIC24FJ128GA010 and have been experimenting on an old explorer 16 board with a similar chipset on a PIM.

I see no options on mplabx to read a hex file off the pic.  Is there a way to read the hex file from a pic using a pickit3?

Yes actually, you can extract the hex out of a PIC but that's assuming it's not read protected. Even if you were extract the hex, you'd have to really know a lot about the assembler to interpret the mnemonics of the machine code.

Assuming the PIC is not read-protected and you can read it, have you read the manual how to read it?

@Colin thanks.  We have the source code so in effect I just need to backup in case my compilation doesn't work.

Yes, if read protection has not been enabled on the device, you can read it with a PICkit 3.
To do this with MPLAB, you open MPLAB IPE, Integrated Programming Environment (not IDE). It is included in the MPLAB X installation if not opted out during install.
The process is pretty straight forward, but if anything is unclear you could have a look in the User Guide.
After opening IPE, you select your target device and your PICkit, and you hit Connect. After that, there is a large Read button in the middle of the display.
In order to export the read HEX, you may need to go into the "Advanced Mode" by selecting Settings->Advanced Mode.

Thanks, that worked for PIC24FJ128GA010 although the hex file is different but it didn't work for PIC24FJ128GA010 .  I get Target Device ID (0x0) is an Invalid Device ID. Please check your connections to the Target Device.  Any ideas?

@SeanJ,You say that the MPLABX IPE worked for the PIC24FJ128GA010, then you found that it didn't work for the PIC24FJ128GA010. So I am guessing that the Explorer16 with the PIC24FJ128GA010 is the working one and your custom board with the PIC24FJ128GA010 is not working. The likely reason for this is an issue with your circuit that prevents In-Circuit-Serial-Programming(ICSP) from working.

@SeanJ, Get someone with more experience using the Microchip ICSP to evaluate your circuit design

@Dan1138 oops, should read --> "it didn't work for PIC24FJ128GC010" Our plan now is to bring someone in with more experience.

@SeanJ, The PIC24FJ128GC010 has significantly different internal peripherals from the PIC24FJ128GA010. The configuration for the system oscillator is very different. That said an ICSP tool like a PICkit3 should be able to read the device ID. That you observe it to read zero suggests connection issues. In any case the HEX file from the PIC24FJ128GA010 will not work in the PIC24FJ128GC010 .

Thanks @Dan1138 I was using PIC24FJ128GA010 for practice. The ipe allowed me to read PIC24FJ128GC010 memory despite the error.  I've been in touch with microchip since who are very helpful but will leave it for the new hire.
